# Vue/Vuetify and binding carousel img src with a method not showing image

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Beginning some Vue/Vuetify and what I'm trying to achieve is binding the image src from a defined method for v-carousel but I am coming up blank.

The loop appears to work and I get to the method correctly and from the function it logs the value I wish to return but it simply isn't displaying that as the source of the image.

```
  <div v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.images+'_'+index">
    <v-carousel-item>
      <img v-bind:src="getImage(index)" alt="">
    </v-carousel-item>
  </div>
  </v-carousel>
```

And for the method I have:

```
getImage (index) {
  butter.content.retrieve(['cardimages'])
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.data.data.cardimages[index]['images_' + index])
      return resp.data.data.cardimages[index]['images_' + index]
    })
}
```

Within the page src I see:

```
img data-v-656039f0="" alt=""
```

And am not sure what that means.Am I way off base on how to do this? What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your getImage function? It should be in the 'methods' that you export. also i think your problem might be trying to get the image after rendering the vue. why not get it before, push it to some array, then bind it after its already retrieved?

Comment: Thanks Jude. Ultimately you led me to the answer, basically instead of trying to get them with a method inline I should've been getting it before and then bind it to the src. I was confused because I was trying to get the image based on the buttercms "slug" so I thought I should get it dynamically. Way easier just to use proper naming on the buttercms content and match with the post slug and get both the post AND the content before hand.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same issue and

`src: require('../assets/hh-home.jpg')`

worked for me

Comment: Simplest answer I've found for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately Jude led me in the right direction and should have been getting the content first and binding from there instead of using a method. This meant using proper naming in the butter cms API to match the slug to content. So the template changed:

```
<div v-for="(cimg, index) in cardimages" :key="post.images+'_'+index">
<v-carousel-item>
<img v-bind:src="cimg[post.slug]" alt="">
</v-carousel-item>
</div>
```

And the method changed to:

```
getContent () {
  butter.content.retrieve(['cardimages'])
    .then((resp) => {
      this.cardimages = resp.data.data.cardimages
    })
}
```

And of course loading on create:

```
  created () {
    this.getPosts()
    this.getContent()
  }
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your image:

```
<img :src="import(getImage(index)) alt="">
```

Comment: Trying this fails compile with causes: "avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "import""

Comment: Ah, so use require instead of important.